# When uploading a screenshot to Slack, it gets uploaded as a "binary file"

Tags: macos, screen-capture

I take a screenshot using <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd>, then upload it to Slack, but it gets uploaded as a "binary file". I can download the file, but to open it, I need to add a ".png" extension first.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to enable "Show all filename extensions" in Finder preferences under Advanced, then relaunch Finder using the Force Quit window.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue. Turns out it wasn't slack that's the problem here. I was running requestly system wide (a tool that monitors and modified network traffic). I switched it off and everything's working now. Check for such tools on your system.